# htaccess file misconfigured

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-routing

I am using codeigniter php framework. I am trying to access a folder under public_html, but I can't get to it. It shows 404 custom page by codeigniter. Does the following script in .htaccess has something to do with it?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|js|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably is, you can try adding either some conditions:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|js|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Or include your folder as part of the exclusion (example, your folder is "foobar"):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|js|images|robots\.txt|foobar)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Excellent job mate. Appreciated